# Excel: check multiple cells for specified values, name the ones that do not match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Ok, so I've tried writing my own formula to make this doable but am drawing a blank.

I want to check multiple columns in a row to see if they contain a specifief value, let's say "V". Then in the final column I want to automatically see which cells did not meet this criteria.

I have a sheet in which each row contains over 25 columns to check with different values, but if I could get the following simplified example working I think it should give me enough input to achieve the rest by myself.

Simplified, here is what I am hoping to achieve (column E being automatically generated):

```
A   B   C   D   E

V   X   V   V    B1
X   V   V   X    A2, D2
V   V   X   X    C3, D3
```

Would really appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely need VBA.  Put this in a Workbook Module, and call like `=return_non_match([range of values],[value you want to find])`

```
Function return_non_match(ByVal target As Range, findMe As String)
Dim cel As Range
Dim cellList As String
For Each cel In target
    If cel.Value <> findMe Then
        cellList = cellList & " " & Replace(cel.Address, "$", "")
    End If
Next cel
return_non_match = Trim(cellList)
End Function
```

[image]

<sub>I admit the name could be better, so obviously feel free to change</sub>

Comment: That's great, it worked! I'll have to tweak it a bit further but I am somewhat famliar with programming so figuring it out should be doable.